# Android playing a sound file

Tags: android, audio

In my res folder I have created a raw folder and have a .mp3 file in there.

I am running this method when a button is clicked:

```
        try{
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clickon);
          mp.start();

        } catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
                 System.out.println("This text is run");
```

Is it that the file is not loaded in enough time, shouls I declare it globally at the top of my class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried implementing your code and it is working fine on my machine. I have following clarifications to ask:

1. What is the context(first argument of MediaPlayer.create method) stands for? Are you sure it is the activity context where you display the button?
2. How have you implemented the setOnClickListener class?
3. Under raw folder have you given the extension(.mp3) to the file you stored?

Comment: The click is trigged by the onclick in the XML of the button.
The context this is on the activity that holds the button.
Yes the extension is on the file, I tried .wav first but tried .mp3 now

Comment: @Jacob: Just a small clarification, it is onClick and not onclick right?

Comment: android:onClick="toggleSound"
And that method is what runs the code I posted

Comment: Sound was on, on my device But in the settings sound for apps was off.
Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do release mediaplayer object after using.

I have used following code for one of my sound playing apps:-

```
private void playSound()
 {
    final MediaPlayer mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.button_sound);
    mp1.start();
    mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
    {   
       @Override
       public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
       {
           Log.v("onCompletion", "sound completed");
           mp1.release();
       }
       });  
}
```